# Expression based on a condition

Tags: angularjs, expression, ternary-operator

I just started practicing `Angular JS`, I got my first output successfully, but when I tried to modify the code based on my condition it gives me bugged output.

I'm providing a `text box` for blood donor to enter his name and a `drop down` to choose his blood group. The first code would show the name and blood group of the donor by the time he gives the data

Sample code :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng-US">
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div ng-app="">
   <div>
    <span>Donor name :  <input type="text" ng-model="donorName"></span>
   </div>
   <div>
    <span>
     Blood group :  <select ng-model="donorGroup">
          <option value="A+">A+</option>
          <option value="A-">A-</option>
          <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
          <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
          <option value="B+">B+</option>
          <option value="B-">B-</option>
          <option value="O+">O+</option>
          <option value="O-">O-</option>
         </select>         
    </span>
   </div>   
   <span> {{donorName}} {{donorGroup}} </span>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

But then I wanted to display it as `<donorName>'s blood group is <donorGroup>` when both `donorName` and `donorGroup` is not empty. I rewrote the code many times, I cannot show all the codes here because it was all wrong, but this is the last thing I tried which is also not working well

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng-US">
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div ng-app="">
   <div>
    <span>Donor name :  <input type="text" ng-model="donorName"></span>
   </div>
   <div>
    <span>
     Blood group :  <select ng-model="donorGroup">
          <option value="A+">A+</option>
          <option value="A-">A-</option>
          <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
          <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
          <option value="B+">B+</option>
          <option value="B-">B-</option>
          <option value="O+">O+</option>
          <option value="O-">O-</option>
         </select>         
    </span>
   </div>   
   <span> {{donorName != null && donorName != '') ? '{{donorName}}'s' blood group is' + {{donorGroup}} : ''}} </span>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

So my doubt is how to insert an expression inside a boolean condition in Angular JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
<span data-ng-show="donorName && donorGroup">{{donorName}} blood group is {{donorGroup}}</span>
```

In the above code, built-in directive `ng-show` is used

Also in case you still want to do it inside interpolation which i think is a not a neat way, you can simply do:

```
<span>{{donorName && donorGroup? donorName + "'s blood group is " + donorGroup: '' }}</span>
```

Comment: good one that lets me know about **data-ng-show**, thanks. But how can we insert an expression inside a boolean condition?

Comment: I did not get your question. Please elaborate @ArunSudhakaran

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran: I have added what you were asking for but that is not a neat way to do things. It will take you or someone else more time to understand when your code will be revisited in future

Comment: I'm completely new to Angular JS and I'm not getting what is name and class, because its not present in my code

Comment: sorry I have edited my answer. That was something I was trying. Changed the variables to what you are using instead @ArunSudhakaran

Comment: thank you so much @Rahul Arora, that gave explanation and clarification to lot of things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147541/discussion-between-arun-sudhakaran-and-rahul-arora).

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran Let me know when you are on chat

Comment: can we chat now

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below code.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app ="sortApp" ng-controller ="mainController">
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng-US">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="">
            <div>
                <span>Donor name :  <input type="text" ng-model="donorName"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>
                    Blood group :   <select ng-model="donorGroup">
                                        <option value="A+">A+</option>
                                        <option value="A-">A-</option>
                                        <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
                                        <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
                                        <option value="B+">B+</option>
                                        <option value="B-">B-</option>
                                        <option value="O+">O+</option>
                                        <option value="O-">O-</option>
                                    </select>                                   
                </span>
            </div>          
            <div> {{ (donorName && donorGroup) ? donorName +'s blood group is' + donorGroup : ''}} </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
                </div>
    <script>
    angular.module('sortApp', [])

    .controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    });
    </script> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


  <div ng-app="">
   <div>
    <span>Donor name :  <input type="text" ng-model="donorName"></span>
   </div>
   <div>
    <span>
     Blood group :  <select ng-model="donorGroup">
          <option value="A+">A+</option>
          <option value="A-">A-</option>
          <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
          <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
          <option value="B+">B+</option>
          <option value="B-">B-</option>
          <option value="O+">O+</option>
          <option value="O-">O-</option>
         </select>         
    </span>
   </div>   
   
   <span> {{donorName!= ''? donorName: ''}}'s blood group is {{donorGroup}} </span>
  </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

});
</script>
</html>
```

Working code snippet

Comment: This will always show the sentence after the interpolation  and the donorGroup